# username and password visible in network tab

Tags: rest, .net-core, http-headers, asp.net-web-api2, angular6

In my .net core WebAPI, during login, I'm passing username and password via post method. My concern is that the password is visible in the request headers of the Network tab which I think is risky. Currently, my web application is in development mode. Will this scenario be changed once my website has HTTPS (hosted on the server) or am I supposed to do something?

Comment: headers or body?

Comment: in the network tab when I see the request headers

Comment: Using HTTPS both headers and content/body are encrypted

Comment: added ssl to the site password can be seen in the request payload of the network tab

Comment: @Matjaž They are still visible in the network tab of the client, which is what the question was about.

Answer (score -1):

You can encrypt the password from front end and send the cipher to your backend , which can then be decrypted back. Usually this works very fast using libraries like JSEncrypt for front end.